# Unknown routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, haml

Im getting this routing error

No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"}

when i click on the new post link from index page it gives me this error, even though in my new post link i cal for new action i dont know y it is calling for show action.

my index page:

```
%h1 All Posts
%html
  %head
  %body
    %table
      %tr
        %th Author Name
        %th Title
        %th Email
        %th description
        %th
        %th
        %th

      - @posts.each do |post|
        %tr
          %td= post.author_name
          %td= post.title
          %td= post.email
          %td= post.description
          %td= link_to 'Show', post
          %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post)
          %td= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete

%br
= link_to 'New Post', :controller => "posts", :action => "new"
```

my edit page:

```
%h1 Update Post

%html
  %head
    %title
  %body
    = form_for(@post) do |f| 
      = f.label :Author_name 
      %br
      = f.text_field :author_name
      %br
      = f.label :Title
      %br
      = f.text_field :title
      %br
      = f.label :Email
      %br
      = f.text_field :email
      %br
      = f.label :Description
      %br
      = f.text_area :description

      %br
      = f.submit

%br
= link_to 'Back', post_path
```

my rake routes:

```
        new_auth_session GET    /auths/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
            auth_session POST   /auths/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
    destroy_auth_session DELETE /auths/sign_out(.:format)           devise/sessions#destroy
           auth_password POST   /auths/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
       new_auth_password GET    /auths/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
      edit_auth_password GET    /auths/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /auths/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
cancel_auth_registration GET    /auths/cancel(.:format)              devise/registrations#cancel
       auth_registration POST   /auths(.:format)                           devise/registrations#create
   new_auth_registration GET    /auths/sign_up(.:format)                    devise/registrations#new
  edit_auth_registration GET    /auths/edit(.:format)                       devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /auths(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /auths(.:format)                            devise/registrations#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                            users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                            users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
           post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                         POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
        new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
       edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
            post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                         PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
                    root        /                                           posts#index
```

Im not able to get why it is searching for 'shows' action when im passing it new..

Comment: Please provide the edit view code instead of the index view code since your problem is when visiting the edit view.

Comment: it all works fine..all other link work fine just the new post link has that error..even if i pass new post link directly on the browser itself it gives same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your link: `link_to 'Back', post_path`

Where `post_path` is singluar, means: Link to *one* post. This would assume that you provide the post or its id, like `link_to 'Back', post_path(@some_other_post)`.

I assume you want to backlink to *all posts*, which would be plural; `link_to 'Back', posts_path` (`posts` instead of `post`).

You can also see this in your routes.

```
post  GET    /posts/:id
posts GET    /posts
```